# Splitting off an Emacs window into a new frame

Tags: emacs

From a frame *first-frame* containing two Emacs windows, *win-one* displaying buffer *buf-one* and *win-two* displaying *buf-two*, I'd like to be able to 'break' *win-two* off into its own frame, perhaps using a modifier-click on the modeline.  After this,

- both *win-one* and *win-two* would retain their individual height/width and buffer associations they had when in *first-frame*
- *win-one* would stay in the same *first-frame*, and *win-two* would now be in a new, separate *second-frame*
- original position, color and font settings would be retained where possible

I was wondering if this behavior was available somewhere in the standard library, if there was an extension for it, or perhaps if a small elisp function would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is such a command: `mouse-tear-off-window`.  I bind it to `C-mouse-1` on the mode line:

```
(global-set-key [mode-line C-mouse-1] 'mouse-tear-off-window)
```

The command is available in vanilla Emacs (`emacs -Q`). But I use my own version of it, which does not delete the window if it is alone in its frame.  Instead, it clones the frame and window.  That version is in library [mouse+.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/mouse%2b.el).  Doc string:

```
,----
| mouse-tear-off-window is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
| `mouse+.el'.
| 
| It is bound to mode-line C-mouse-1.
| 
| (mouse-tear-off-window EVENT)
| 
| Create a new frame displaying buffer of window clicked on.
| If window is not the only one in frame, then delete it.
| Otherwise, this command effectively clones the frame and window.
`----
```

Comment: This is close enough to my request that I think I can extend it to preserve other frame properties.

Answer (score 2):

This is a default binding:

```
C-x 5 C-o : display-buffer-other-frame
```

Which does: Display buffer BUFFER in another frame.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
M-x new-frame
```

I've bound it to <kbd>F9</kbd>, for example:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f9>") 'new-frame)
```

Comment: That leaves the buffer that is in the new frame also in the old frame.